# How to access WolframWebEngine running on a remote server?

Tags: python, free-wolfram-engine, wolfram-client

Thanks to [WolframWebEngine](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframWebEngineForPython) it's extremely easy to build and run a webapp backed by the Wolfram Engine **on a local machine**. 
Assuming one has all dependencies installed on a remote server, what is the most straightforward method to build a public webapp based on WolframWebEngine?
Perhaps by modifying django config? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

thank you we are trying to it easy for everyone to do it.

The default server shipped with the project is using aiohttp, you need to install python3 and all dependencies in the remote server.

Once you have done that you can run the demo by using this command:

```
python3 -m wolframwebengine --demo
```

this will effectively start the aiohttp application, then you can follow the official instructions to deploy the application on production using nginx.

https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/deployment.html

If you want to use django (maybe because you also want to use python), there is one example in the repo.

https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframWebEngineForPython/blob/master/wolframwebengine/examples/djangoapp/

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thank You. Eventually I managed to run WolframWebEngine on my VPS by specifying the options  `--domain`, `--port` and `--index`

Comment: Is there an easy option to make it serve https instead of http?